# Like/Dislike function with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table in my Thymeleaf template which shows database data. I have additional two columns which contain Like and Dislike buttons for each row. I want to enable liking/disliking "posts". My idea was to simply increment Like/Dislike count in a database by updating database entity. So, in my template I got this:

```
<table id="css-serial" class="table table-striped table-inverse">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Kategorija</th>
        <th>Vic</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
        <th>Razlika</th>
        <th>Like</th>
        <th>Dislike</th>
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="joke : ${jokes}">
        <form method="POST" th:object="${updateJoke}" th:action="@{/}">
        <td></td>
        <td> <pre th:text="${joke.getCatName()}"></pre> </td>
        <td> <div class="preforma" th:text="${joke.getContent()}" th:field="*{content}"></div> </td>
        <td th:text="${joke.getLikes()}" th:field="*{likes}"></td>
        <td th:text="${joke.getDislikes()}" th:field="*{dislikes}"></td>
        <td th:text="${joke.likesDislikesSubtraction()}"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Svidja mi se" name="like"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Ne svidja mi se" name="dislike"/></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller GET and POST methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showJokes(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("jokes", jokeService.listAllJokes());
    return "jokestable";
}

@RequestMapping(params="like", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String likeJoke(Joke joke, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("updateJoke", joke);
    jokeService.likeJoke(joke);
    return showJokes(model);
}

@RequestMapping(params="dislike", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String dislikeJoke(Joke joke, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("updateJoke", joke);
    jokeService.dislikeJoke(joke);
    return showJokes(model);
}
```

Relevant methods in service layer:

```
public void likeJoke(Joke joke){
    jokeRepository.likeJoke(joke.getContent());
}

public void dislikeJoke(Joke joke){
    jokeRepository.dislikeJoke(joke.getContent());
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface JokeRepository extends CrudRepository<Joke, Long> {

Joke findByContent(String content);

@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Joke j SET j.likes = j.likes+1 WHERE j.content=:content")
void likeJoke(@Param("content") String content);

@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Joke j SET j.dislikes=j.dislikes+1 WHERE j.content=:content")
void dislikeJoke(@Param("content") String content);
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, and every time I hit the Like button, nothing happens, but when I go to IntelliJ, I see "Request method 'GET' not supported" (first time after refresh it shows this two times for each button, then every next time, only once). Is this solution even possible, or I have to change my approach? Any ideas?

P.S. Service class is annotated with @Transactional

If anyone wonders why do I

```
return showJokes(model);
```

it's because if I return template name, it doesn't show database data anymore when I hit the buttons, there's just empty table then (only th elements).

I suppose that possible problem could be that every Like button for every row is named the same, as well as Dislike buttons. But I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Take a good look at what [RequestMapping annotation properties mean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html). You got `params` and `path` mixed up, it looks like.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I am a beginner at all this, I could mix up anything.... I'll take a look at the docs you linked here. Thank you for your advice.